# A circle is random popping up in my css animation

Tags: css, animation

Can someone explain me where the little blue circle comes from which is on right right bottom edge of the white circle? It's coming at the end of my animation and I don't know where it's from, I even tried to reset the animation at 100% to all 0% but it doesn't worked out.

It's written in SCSS, I'll include the link to a codepen here: [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/Lueh/pen/Moojma)

**SCSS:**

```
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

.content-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.box{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
}

.ping{
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    animation: ping 1.6s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes ping{
    0% {
        width: 60%;
        height: 60%;
        left: 20%;
        top: 20%;
        border: 80px solid rgba(102, 217, 255, .5);
    }

    80% {
        width: 160%;
        height: 160%;
        left: -30%;
        top: -30%;
        border: 4px solid rgba(102, 217, 255, 1);
    }

    99% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        border: 0px solid rgba(102, 217, 255, 1);
        width: 0%;
        height: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        top: 0%;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="ping"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the animation `16s` instead of `1.6s` and add an outline to the `.ping` element you will see the problem (*how the element moves*)

---

You are better off using `transform` to center a size changing element instead of animating the `left` and `top`

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

.content-wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.box{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 position: absolute;
}

.ping{
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 animation: ping 1.6s ease-out infinite;
 
 transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
}

@keyframes ping{
 0% {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  border: 80px solid rgba(102, 217, 255, .5);
 }
 
 80% {
  width: 160%;
  height: 160%;
  border: 4px solid rgba(102, 217, 255, 1);
 }
 
 99% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 
 100% {
  border: 0px solid rgba(102, 217, 255, 1);
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
 <div class="box">
  <div class="ping"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you verry much, it clearly worked out pretty nice, I updated my pen now with your code. I hope this is fine!

Comment: @LUEH you are welcome. Of course you can use the code on your pen.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the `ping` keyframes:

```
@keyframes ping {
  border: 80px solid rgba(102, 217, 255, .5);
}
```

Which is then called in the `animation` for `.ping`:

```
animation: ping 1.6s ease-out infinite;
```

The blue colour that you see is `rgba(102, 217, 255, .5)`.

To remove this, remove all instance of `border` inside each of the `@keyframes ping` percentages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I dont mean the blue circle in general, this is on purpose, look on the right edge on the bottom when the animation ends there is a little blue edge of a circle that you can see. I dont know where it's coming from! :(

Comment: There is no additional blue edge of a circle for me, and this certainly does not come from your code shown; only the main circle is generated. I'd try refreshing your browser's cached CSS by holding `SHIFT` while clicking the refresh icon.

Comment: Usually it was not displayed in your browser or something, but it was definitely there, I dont know what browser Gaby is using but he saw the edge of the circle down there to. He fixed the problem, so everything is fine now :) And thanks for your help!